# EasyNetQ Publish method not found

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I have been going through the set up for EasyNetQ https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Quick-Start

The following code

```
using System;
using EasyNetQ;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost"))
        {
            var input = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a message. 'Quit' to quit.");
            while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "Quit")
            {
                bus.Publish(new TextMessage
                {
                    Text = input
                });
            }
```

Throws this error, on the bus.Publish line
Error   CS1929  'IBus' does not contain a definition for 'Publish' and the best extension method overload 'PubSubExtensions.Publish(IPubSub, TextMessage, CancellationToken)' requires a receiver of type 'IPubSub'    PetStore.StockDelivery.Publish

I have EasyNetQ installed

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EasyNetQ" Version="5.3.0-alpha0074" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I added this through nuget and got RabbitMQ and other dependancys

When I look at what is available on IBus

```
IPubSub PubSub { get; }
IRpc Rpc { get; }
ISendReceive SendReceive { get; }
IScheduler Scheduler { get; }
IAdvancedBus Advanced { get; }
```

Is there something I am missing?
I aslo have RabbitMQ server running okay on my mashine on localhost and I have tested that works

Answer (score 1):

They moved it under PubSub property. See code example below:

```
 public class Publisher<T>
    {
        IBus bus;
        public Publisher()
        {
            bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost");
        }
        
        public async void Send(T message)
        {            
            await bus.PubSub.PublishAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);              
             
        }
    }
```